# navbar-right is not working on list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and in my application I want to have a `navbar` at the top of the page. The `navbar` should contain the brand name and then to the right of it it should have some options. But whenever I use `navbar-right` it doesn't work and the page I get looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ucr.jpg)

As you can see everything is squashed together with the brand name on the left hand side. What I have tried to fix this is by using `pull-right` which does work perfectly but I want to know why `navbar-right` isn't.

homeTemplate.html

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="container-fluid"> 
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyApp</a>
           </div> 
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you might have missed some library.

See the given below snippet I have added

Jquery library

bootstrap.js and

bootstrap.css

Its working fine. see the below snippet

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
       <div class="container-fluid"> 
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MyApp</a>
           </div> 
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just a heads up for bootstrap 4 users, the recommended class is        
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"> to move elements to the right

Comment: Yes If anybody is using BOOTSTRAP 4 then they can use the above solution given by @StephenRomero. The code which I have added is for people who are using BOOTSTRAP 3.

Comment: @StephenRomero You should make your Comment an answer, I nearly oversaw it. But It worked nicely :)

Comment: Your code ```nav navbar-nav navbar-right``` from the ```ul``` is just what I needed to move my navbar to the right in BS-4 when migrating from BS3

Answer (score 3):

There might be a version issue. For Bootstrap version 4, Use `<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">` for moving element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **two Unordered-Lists**, one for the **nav-brand** and the elements you require to be aligned left and then use **separate unordered-lists** with the **"nav navbar-nav navbar-right"** class to get the right aligned elements. Check the snippet below.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="topnav">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="navbar-brand bigbrand" href="{% url 'urls' %}">BRAND name</a></li>       
                <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'urls' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class = "navbar-link" href="urls">News</a></li>
                <li><a class = "navbar-link" href="urls">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class = "navbar-link" href="{% url 'urls' %}">test</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="{% url 'url:logout' %}">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
</nav>
```